# How to keep the missing values when using ifelse in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a subset of data as below. I would like to make a new column to say if all the values in column x1, x2 and x3 is one, then "yes" and if it is two then "no".

```
structure(list(x1 = c("1", "1", "1", "2", NA, "2", "2", NA,NA, "1", "1", "1"), 
           x2 = c(NA, NA, "1", NA, "2", NA, "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
           x3 = c(NA, NA, "1", NA, "2", NA,"1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1")), 
           class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I tried below, but it is not correct. I appreciate your help.

```
d$new <- ifelse(!is.na(d$x1 ==1 & d$x2 ==1 d$x3 ==1 ), "yes","no")
```

Comment: So if all three are 1, then you want "yes", but of two are 1, then "no". But what if only one is 1? Are 2's different from NA? ALso it's a bit odd that you seem to be combining actual `NA` values with strings that have the value `"NA"`. Do you know how that happened to your data? Because that's something you'll likely want to fix first.

Comment: @MrFlick I fixed the "NA", however this is just an example of my large data. I want to say for each row if all the columns (variables) are 1, say "yes" and if all are 2, say "no" and keeping the NAs as NAs

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this by using case_when expression from tidyverse.
You need to start by activating tidyverse library:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

After that the code would look something like this:

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "NA", "2", "2", "NA","NA", "1", "1", "1"), 
           x2 = c(NA, NA, "1", "NA", "2", "NA", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
           x3 = c(NA, NA, "1", NA, "2", "NA","1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1")), 
      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Edit : Added a check statements for NAs as well. In case_when in tidyverse, NAs need to be of the right class. Since, the class of our new column here is supposed to be char, as.charcter(NA) has been included.

```
df <- df |> mutate(new_col = case_when(
  x1 == 1 & x2 == 1 & x3 == 1 ~ "Yes",
  x1 == 2 & x2 == 2 & x3 == 2 ~ "No",
  is.na(x1) | is.na(x1) | is.na(x1) ~ as.character(NA)))
```

The mutate expression makes a new column and the case when is for doing the if else conditioning. For more clarification you can visit this link https://stringr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: thanks. But I want to say for each row if all the values are 1 , then say "yes" and if all are 2 say , "no" and if there is any NA, keep it as NA

Comment: Hello, thanks for the clarification. I believe the edit should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
d$new <- ifelse(d$x1 ==1 & d$x2 ==1 & d$x3 ==1 , "yes",
               ifelse(d$x1 ==2 & d$x2 ==2 & d$x3 ==2 , "no", NA))
```

Comment: It is not what I want. Please see my comment. Thanks

Comment: What about this edit?

Answer (score 0):

```r
d$new <- ifelse(apply(d==1, 1, prod), 'yes', 'no')
```

`d==1` creates a logical matrix with `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NA` where 1, not 1 and `NA` were in `d`, respectively. Then, applying `prod` to rows of this matrix you get 1 in case of all `TRUE`'s, 0 in case of at least one `FALSE` (and no `NA`) and `NA` when there is at least one `NA`.